# Get jQuery Selectable id values using js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

I have table with five different `<tr class="selectable" id="1">` with id values 1 to 5.

```
<table>
    <tr class="selectable" id="1">
      <td class="notselectable"><b>Minor</b></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
     </tr>    
    <tr class="selectable" id="2">
     <td class="notselectable"><b>major</b></td>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

.... up to 5 selectable where id = 3, 4, 5.

Now say if user select any element from  to   then get highest selected id values (say if they  pick 5 and 4 then highest values 5 will be stored in db) and ignore other selected values.

```
$(function () {
    $(".selectable").selectable();
    $(".notselectable").selectable({ disabled: true });
});
```

[Selecatable UI:](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid)

Comment: php runs serverside, before javascript can even run. You can pass the variable to PHP by `POST`-ing the page or by using AJAX but you can't set a php variable with javascript.

Comment: @serakfalcon Can I please know How can i get value of selected id?

Comment: @DXLIVE, tell us the end goal instead of asking us how to fix your solution. You'll likely get an entirely new solution. ([XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=xy+problem))

Comment: It seems like what you're really asking is how do you get the ID of the selected element from jQuery UI selectable plugin, and then send it to PHP (eg. via a hidden field or ajax call). Is that correct?

Comment: @itsmejodie Yes. Highest selected id from 1 to 5 from <tr>

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by highest ID, but you can handle the [selected](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected) event to find out what was selected and then implement your logic